# AngularJS - CSS3 animation of height (auto) - sometimes works

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, css-animations

I want to animate an element, that I don't know the actual height, that's why I am using the `trick` with `max-height`.

the css is pretty simple:

```
.animate-enter-setup, .animate-leave-setup {
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animate-enter-setup {
  opacity:0;
  max-height: 0;
}
.animate-enter-setup.animate-enter-start {
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity:1;
}

.animate-leave-setup{
  opacity:1;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.animate-leave-setup.animate-leave-start {
  opacity:0;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

In the example here:
http://plunker.co/edit/AoirGQoOKsflunxj9RGV?p=preview the `leave` animation get's only applied when the item didn't finish previous `enter` animation.
When the item did finish `enter` animation, the `leave` animation doesn't get applied (well it does as a class but there is no visual efect).

I suspect there is something wrong with the CSS rather than in angular. But I have no idea what would that be.

Comment: FYI: both your links are broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that if you want to use the `max-height` trick, then the element that you want to animate must have defined `max-height` and `overflow:hidden` (not only on animation class)

The strange thing here is that the `setup` animation class doesn't get applied by the browser even it is on the element.

updated example: http://plunker.co/edit/qnEFDhAyGqhsJdCGrF71?p=preview

I think this may be a bug either in angular or chrome.